# Creating an asp.net handler to get Request info on image files?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

First time asking a question here so thanks in advance for your time.

I have this issue:

I am hosting image files (jpg, png, gif) in a folder of my ASP.NET 4.0 application. I know that some people hot link these images as avatars or pictures in other forums, blogs, etc... . I would like to know where.

Searching a little, I found that I can create a custom HTTP handler to serve these files and then have the handler return me a string of the URL where it is accessed from. Unfortunately, I only did basic coding in ASP.NET and this HTTP handler stuff is a little bit over my comprehension. Could anybody point me towards a sample of how it's done?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can't you just check the referer in the IIS logs?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx

Comment: @GregB: It sounds like he might want to take it a step further and even deny such direct linking.

Comment: You can check this [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomImageHandler.aspx) example for where to start at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll want to implement IHttpHandler. then in the web.config map this handler to the type(s) of extensions/requests you want to handle. for example all requests for jpg or gif. IHttpHandler has 2 members to implement

```
bool IsResuable {get;}
void Process(HttpContext context)
```

IsResuable informs asp.net whether a new handler must be initialized for every request, or if the handler can be cached. Process is where the work is done. from Context you have access to everything in the request and response.

Comment: It is a far stretch from what I need but it pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: how so? i'm curious, because this is the what http handlers were designed for. handling http requests for any type of resource.